How can I clip off / crop out a piece of a .MOV file using a free tool?
I tried using ClipChamp to remove some sections of a video. I dragged the sidebars to the point where I want the video to end, but I see no way to then save this new/improved/shortened version. Is saving only available in the paid edition?
I then downloaded movavi, and it seemed as if I was able to crop what I wanted, but then when I went to save the file, it wouldn't allow me to do it with the free version because my video is over the 60-second limit for the free edition.
Is there a free software or web site where I can upload a video and then have it cut off the first second or two and the last second or two of my video?

What platform are you working on? Windows / PC / Mac / something else?

Windows 11 (not to be confused with Oceans 11)

I found Veed.IO to work well and easily; it is an online tool that can be found here. The free version puts a watermark (Veed.IO) on the video, but for my purposes that doesn't bother me.
I chopped one second off the start of the video and 2 seconds off the end rather easily.
The .mpf file it generated is larger than my original .MOV file, but that additional size shouldn't be a problem, either.
